# Laravel 4 - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm trying to show a foreach data form a pivot table in Laravel 4. I'm doing in the same way I've done before, but now it doesn't work. I'm doing something wrong... And I don't know what! Here's my code:

**My models:**

```
Ficha

public function contenidos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Contenido', 'contenido_ficha')->withTimestamps();
}

Contenido

public function fichas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Ficha', 'contenido_ficha')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function myShow($id, $slug)
{
    $ficha = Ficha::where('id', $id)->first();

    $date = $ficha->created_at;
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Europe/Madrid');
    $date = $date->formatlocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

    return View::make('fichas.show')
        ->with('ficha', $ficha)
        ->with('date', $date);
}
```

**My View:**

```
@foreach ($ficha->contenidos as $contenido)
    {{ $contenido->nombre }}
@endforeach
```

Thank you very much for any help!!

Comment: This code is OK, problem lies somewhere else. However I suggest you set locale in app/config instead of `setlocale()`

Comment: Thanks @deczo, and any idea about what could be the problem??

Comment: Do you happen to have another `foreach` there?

Comment: No, that is the first time I've had this error... And I have no more `foreach` in this page.

Comment: Check stack trace and make sure where the error occured. From the code you pasted, nothing would cause that, since `$ficha` is an object for sure, and `$ficha->contenido` is a collection, even if empty, it wouldn't make foreach cry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you're not checking whether `$ficha` actually has any `contenido`.

```
@if ($ficha->contenidos->count())
    @foreach ($ficha->contenidos as $contenido)
        {{ $contenido->nombre }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I think I got it, the problem was in my migration... I created a column called 'contenidos'. And I suppose it would be a kind of problem. I've deleted this column and now it works correctly! Thanks for your help!